# Копирование фрагмента текста с TextView

Tags: android, select, textview

Нужно реализовать выделение текста?

`android:textIsSelectable="true"` не подходит к моей задаче

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает `android:textIsSelectable="true"`? Не раскрывая этого вы сильно снижаете вероятность получить ответ, т.к. без этой информации вам нечего ответить по сущесвту

Comment: использую библиотеку для определения разных ссылок  и использую метод setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); а на Android 4.2 и 4.3 не работает setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())

Comment: Приведите минимальный код того как вы ссылки кликабельными сделали и как выделение сделали. И укажите в вопросе где этот код не работает